# Se puede crear lo siguiente? (migración de usuarios con configuracion de impresora y red mediante powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell

Estamos en mi empresa intentando ver si hay una manera de crear un script de powershell que pudiese hacer lo siguiente, copiar el perfil de un usuario (están en AD y cuando inician sesión en una máquina se les crea un usuario "nuevo" en dicha máquina) con sus rutas de red y asociados a una impresora que tengan configurada en red.

Por poner un ejemplo, si uno de mis usuarios está en almería y tiene X unidades de red asignadas y tiene X impresora de red asociada, que cuando se cambie a un equipo nuevo porque el antiguo vayamos ya a jubilarlo, el perfil copiado tenga configuradas ya las unidades de red y la impresora.

¿Alguna idea?

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que creo hay varias opciones paso dos de puro powershell(1,2), una de puro AD(3) y una mixta(4):

1. En caso de tener conexión entre sí y un usuario con permisos de administrador parametros(ip entrada,ip salida, usuario,contrasenya). para loggear( ver cmd Logon),una vez logeado en el otro usuario puedes copiar documentos (ver xcopy), para impressoras (ver powershell get-Printer,Set-printer), para unidades de red (ver powershell Get-PsDrive,New-PsDrive)

**Ventajas:**

-no hace falta ad

-se puede ejecutar a distancia de los dos pc

-sirve para usuarios locales

**Desventajas:**

-Es un script grande y lento

-Requiere mantenerlo para las actualizaciones de Windows.

-Puede duplicar en caso de políticas de grupo que afecten a las impresoras y discos

-no se puede ejecutar sin conexión entre los pc

2.Caso en que no están conectados entre sí pero en dominio. Script d'entrada que genera un script de salida para ejecutar en el ordenador nuevo.

**Ventajas:**

-no hace falta ad

-se puede ejecutar sin conexión a los dos pc entre si

-sirve para usuarios locales

**Desventajas:**

-Son dos scripts en realidad, el segundo pesara mucho ( con los ficheros que saque adjunto)

-Requiere mantenerlo para las actualizaciones de Windows.

-Puede duplicar en caso de políticas de grupo que afecten a las impresoras y discos

-no se puede ejecutar a distancia entre los dos pc

3.Con AD pudes prevenir meter en politicas las unidades de red del usuario o grupos y impressoras compartidas de forma que ya se le cargaran automaticamente y puedes plantearte si hacer perfiles dinamicos para que los documentos se carguen y copien de un lado a otra para el usuario.(ver cmd gpudate /force para actualizar políticas en el ordenador)

**Ventajas:**

-No existe script y no hace falta mantenimiento para compatibilidad

-Se puede cambiar sin usar un paso previo

-Se puede consultar centralizadamente desde el ad lo que tiene el usuario

**Desventajas:**

-Tienes que haber creado las políticas previamente

-El usuario probablemente tenga un límite de capacidad más pequeño

-Tienes que mantener las políticas actualizadas

4.(La que uso yo) políticas de grupo para impresoras compartidas y unidades de red. Y un pequeño script para copiar los documentos con xcopy

**Ventajas**

-script pequeño y ligero para copiar los documentos locales

-Se puede consultar centralizadamente desde el ad lo que tiene el usuario

**Desventajas:**

-Tienes que haber creado las políticas previamente

-Tienes que mantener las políticas actualizadas

Comment: PD: esto tenia que ser un comentario pero debido a la longitud exagerada esta como respuesta